Why would Windows Defender pop up when I try to empty the recycle bin in Windows 10?
Something I've never seen before: when I open up the recycle bin and use Recycle Bin Tools -> Empty Recycle Bin from the menu, I get a Windows Defender popup with the following text:
Windows protected your PC
Microsoft Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.

App: 
$RXKQRC5.exe 
Publisher:  
Open Source Developer, OSCAR GONZALEZ MORENO

By searching the recycle bin for the exe's obfuscated name, I was able to figure out that it was originally an installer from https://zen-browser.app/ that I downloaded, but deleted without ever running - hence why Defender doesn't trust it.
But here's what I don't understand. Why in the hell would emptying the recycle bin cause Windows to run an executable that's in the recycle bin!? Or if it's not actually trying to run it, why does Windows Defender think that it's trying to run it?
Since some comments seem to misunderstand, I'll reiterate that my question is not why the exe in question is in the recycle bin (I sent it there knowingly and on purpose), nor how to otherwise get rid of it (I know how to do that), but specifically why emptying the recycle bin would cause it to run, as that is a bizarre and unexpected behavior.

Windows Defender isn’t attempting to run the executable, it prevented the executable, from being ran.

hiding things in the recycle bin is A Thing(tm) unfortunately

Have you tried going into the Recycle Bin, finding the offending file, and then manually deleting it directly, rather than using the "Empty Recycle Bin" function?

MS recommends deleting the $Recycle.bin file: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-remove-ribbz2hexe-virus-from-recyclebin/94f30e1e-7bb8-4838-a73b-293061a1831b
